# Fetching the HWND of a Win32 control using global screen coordinates

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, ui-automation, user32

##### Background

I need to implement some Spy++-esque functionality for an Windows application automation project.
For simplicity's sake, let us assume that my application `A` (written in C# or C++) is trying to automate an existing **Win32 Application** `B` (not a WPF or OpenGL application). Let us also assume that application `B` has a picture-box which I'd like to capture. The exact size and location of this picture box inside of `B` is not known at runtime, as it is dynamically created and resized by `B`. However, one can be certain that the global screen coordinates `(x, y)` will always be inside the picture box in question.

##### Question

I can retrieve the main window handle of `B` at runtime using `[user32.dll] FindWindow`. However, the picture box inside `B` has a HWND which is unknown to my application (`A`) at runtime. Can I retrieve the picture box' HWND if I know that it is positioned under the global screen coordinates `(x, y)` when `B` is maximized and in the foreground?

i.e. something like this:
[image]
when being positioned over a specific pair of screen coordinates.

#### Edit No.1:

I tried the solution proposed by [@David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) in the comments (namely the usage of the function (`[user32.dll] WindowFromPoint`)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint], however this did **NOT** work:

```
void* window_hwnd = FindWindow(null, "<title of the window>");

SendMessage(window_hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);
ShowWindow(window_hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
SetForegroundWindow(window_hwnd);
SetActiveWindow(window_hwnd);
SetWindowPos(window_hwnd, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
RedrawWindow(window_hwnd, null, null, RDW_FRAME | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ALLCHILDREN);

void* control_hwnd = WindowFromPoint(300, 300);
```

This should theoretically give me the HWND to the control at position `(x=300, y=300)`. However, `control_hwnd` has the same value as `window_hwnd`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint

Comment: I think this will very much depend on the architecture of B. If B uses a GUI framework such as WPF, there are no HWNDs for individual controls, because WPF doesn't create Windows controls for window contents.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What language are you using: C++ or c#?

Comment: For automating applications on Win32, the best API to use is UI Automation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32 and it has a IUIAutomation::ElementFromPoint method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation-elementfrompoint (you don't necessarily need to work with HWND)

Comment: **@DavidHeffernan** Thank you for this proposal, however, it did unfortunately _not_ work. I have updated my post.

**@PMF** It is a traditional Win32-application. No WPF, UWP, or OpenGL. The handle of the control in question is obtainable using Spy++.

**@Charlieface** I am using C# for now, but my language choice does not really matter, as long as I am able to access the WinAPI. I can just as well use C++....

**@SimonMourier** Thank you, I will have a look at these resources.

Comment: The observed behavior seems to be in line with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint): *"If the point is over a static text control, the return value is a handle to the window under the static text control."* A "picture box" is usually implemented as a [static control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-controls) with the [`SS_BITMAP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-control-styles) style set.

Comment: @unknown6656 yes, WindowFromPoint does work. The fact that it doesn't do what you want is indicative that you have not asked quite the right question.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the comment of [@Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) under my original post, I was able to create a working solution using the [Windows UI Automation APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) by means of the [FlaUI wrapper library for C#](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI).

I will mark that (for now) as the accepted answer, however, if someone has a better alternative, I will be gladly accepting the respective answer.

Comment: While this may solve *your* immediate problem, it doesn't actually answer the question. That's a common outcome when practicing the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @IInspectable I absolutely agree with you. I wish that I'd have a better answer for now, but unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: It's not so much that you don't have a good answer. It's more that you didn't have the right question.